# Map Observable of Array using Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I try to find a way to get this scenario working :

- I have an observable `talks$` which emits a list of all talks.
- A talk have a property `personId`
- This property can be mapped to the person using an Observable.
- I try to map it into a class `TalkWithPerson`

```js
const test = this.talks$.pipe(
  exhaustMap(talks =>
    talks.map(t => this.getPersonById(t.personId).pipe(map(p => newTalkWithPerson(t, p))))
  ),
);
```

Currently, this emits 2 observable, each one emitting my `TalkWithPerson` object. (`Observable<Observable<TalkWithPerson>>`)

I would like to have an `Observable<TalkWithPerson[]>` if possible.

I was thinking going the hard way with getting all the people and all the talks and use `combineLatest` with a project function to match the records but I don't want to load all the persons, it will cause to load a huge list...

Thank you for your help !

StackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/talks-person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const test = this.talks$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(talks =>
        from(talks)
            .pipe(
                mergeMap(t => this.getPersonById(t.personId).pipe(map(p => newTalkWithPerson(t, p)))),                  
                toArray())
            )
  ),
);
```

- Import `from` as creation method `import { from } from "rxjs";`
- Import `toArray` same as the 'map' pipeable operator

Comment: toArray cause the observable to not emit, certainly because the source is not completed

Comment: The toArray here is on the inner observable that is created from 'talks'. By the name 'getPersonById' I assumed it is an observable that completes after one value. Lmk if it doesn't and I will edit my answer.

Comment: I change the method getPersonById to get completed after one value and it's working, thanks !

Comment: But could you give me a way if getPersonById will not return once? Just for learning :)

Comment: If it doesn't complete immediately you should decide on when to collect all the emitted items and transform them to array. It really depends on your case, but here are some options: 
Take only the first item from 'getPersonById' - You can use take(1) in the pipe before 'map'.
Buffer items and emit them after period of time has passed - check the buffer operators

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap` operator for this. `flatMap` will unwrap an `Observable<Observable<TalkWithPerson[]>>` into `Observable<TalkWithPerson[]>`

So try doing this:

```
const test = this.talks$.pipe(
  exhaustMap(talks =>
    talks.flatMap(t => this.getPersonById(t.personId).pipe(map(p => newTalkWithPerson(t, p))))
  ),
);
```

Comment: exhaustMap(talks => : here talks is not an observable so no flatMap and the dot notation for rxjs is dead btw

Comment: Can you create a stackbliz if possible?